# Optimize VBA Code to run faster

Tags: vba, optimization

friends,

I am using this code below to calculate results with two arrays of variables x,y  (longitude and latitude) in a matrix. Because the formula is complicated, it takes very long time to get all the results. Can anyone help me optimize the code so that it runs faster? Thank you!

The code runs between two tabs, VBA Calculation Sheet and Sheet 2.The first array starts at Cell A3 and the second array starts at cell  B1.

```
Sub calculator()
Worksheets("Sheet2").Select

Dim long1 As Double
Dim lat1 As Double


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
x = 3
y = 2
While IsEmpty(Cells(x, 1)) = False

lat1 = Cells(x, 1).value



While IsEmpty(Cells(1, y)) = False

long1 = Cells(1, y).value

Worksheets("VBA Calculation Sheet").Select
Cells(28, 7) = lat1
Cells(29, 7) = long1

index = Cells(23, 7).value


Worksheets("Sheet2").Select

Cells(x, y) = index

y = y + 1
Wend

x = x + 1
y = 2

Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: If the code works then you need to post this question, with a better title, on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  it is too broad for this forum, but perfect for that one.

Comment: I would read up on working with arrays. Your code is slow because it is constantly interacting with the worksheet. It is better to store data in arrays, and process it within the code (in memory). Then output the final results to the worksheet if needed.

Comment: You also will want to show the calculations being done on the sheet.  To speed things up you will want to limit the number of times you need to refer to the sheet.  One should load an array, iterate through that array doing the calculations in the code and load another array for output. That way you are only acessing the worksheets 2 or 3 times.  This is the main slow down as well as using `.Select`.

Answer (score 0):

`.Select` consume a lot of resources. A better way to run your code is using Arrays. Make sure to define an array type different as `Variant` to reduce the memory consumption.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Oh got it! Thank you so much I will change it to arrays